# Setup checkstyle as part of java project build process

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jenkins, checkstyle

I am working on adding checkstyle to the build process of a java project. The results of the checkstyle will be later displayed on jenkins. I am using java7 & netbeans 7.2.1

For most of the work I am following the instructions on this page: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html

However, i'm a beginner in java (& jenkins) and some of the instructions do not make sense to me:

1- The doc says: "To use the task in a build file, you will need the following taskdef declaration: ". 
Question: is this to be added in the build.xml file? or where?

2- Then the doc goes on describing a set of parameters and provides some examples. Are these to be added to build.xml too? or?

3- Checkstyle uses a configuration file. I'll be using the standard sun_checks.xml. Where should this be placed?

If someone can point me out to a step by step tutorial for the whole process, i'd be most grateful.
Thx in advance for all answers

I am using the following in my build.xml:

```
<taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties"
     classpath="libs/checkstyle-5.6-all.jar"/>

<target name="checkstyle"
        description="Generates a report of code convention violations.">

    <checkstyle config="sun_checks.xml"
                  failureProperty="checkstyle.failure"
                  failOnViolation="false">
        <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
        <formatter type="xml" toFile="checkstyle-results.xml"/>
    </checkstyle>

    <style in="checkstyle-results.xml" out="checkstyle_report.html" style="checkstyle.xsl"/>

</target>
```

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use Sonar. Checkstyle is one of the tools automatically run on your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes, you must add it in your build.xml
2. These attributes and elements are attributes and elements of the `<checkstyle>` ant task, which you can use in your build file thanks to the taskdef you have added in point 1. And yes, this `<checkstyle>` task must be used in your build.xml.
3. You place it wherever you want. you just need to give its path to the `<checkstyle>` task using its `config` attribute.

Comment: Thx for the answer JB Nizet
Shouldn't i get the report xml file when i "ant all"?
Please check the edited question for the script i'm using in build.xml

Comment: It's impossible to say, as you don't show what the `all` target does. `ant all` doesn't mean "execute all the targets". It means "execute the target named `all` (and its dependencies).

Comment: right right! again, newb mistake.
i had to add checkstyle to the "all" target
<target name="all" description="build all programs"
            depends="junit_test, checkstyle"/>

thx again

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what build management you are using. If you are using [Gradle](https://gradle.org), you can use [`gradle-estilo-plugin`](https://github.com/anshulverma/gradle-estilo-plugin). It sets up the entire checkstyle configuration you need directly from a gradle config block.

Here is what you'll need to get started:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'net.anshulverma.gradle:gradle-estilo-plugin:0.4.8'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'net.anshulverma.gradle.estilo'

estilo {
  source 'sun'
}
```